# Dynamic checkBox text above checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I am currently creating dynamic checkBoxes and putting them on a panel like this:

```
  CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
  chk.Text = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
  chk.Location = new Point(10, i * 25);
  panelSubfolders.Controls.Add(chk);          
  i++;
```

But on the panel, the text of the checkBox is not directly in the middle of the checkBox rather a bit above of it. How can I fix that?
The strange thing is, it doesnt happen for every checkBox I add, some look ok.

Comment: Im guessing your adding it and the label is being wrapped. Probably because its next to another element.

Comment: Do look into the CheckBox.TextAlign property!

Comment: Check the size of the checkbox.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.checkbox.autosize%28v=office.15%29.aspx Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making sure the AutoSize property is set before assigning the checkbox its text.

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.AutoSize = true;
chk.Text = new DirectoryInfo(folder).Name;
chk.Location = new Point(10, i * 25);
panelSubfolders.Controls.Add(chk);          
i++;
```

Otherwise, you may have to set the size of the checkbox yourself based off of a calculation that uses the length of the text to calculate size in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of create only checkboxes try to create dinamically checkboxes with empty text and creating dinamically asp.net Label assigning text.

At the end you can play with css